# Python Index error using generator with yield

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running this code and I get the values I want from it, but there is also an `IndexError: tuple index out of range` for lines 12 and 18

```
import statistics as st

def squares(*args):
    i = 0
    val = []
    fin = []
    val = args

    while True:
        avg = (st.mean(val))
        fin = (avg - val[i]) ** 2  # line 12
        yield fin
        i += 1

mylist = squares(3, 4, 5)
for x in mylist:  # line 18
    print(x)
```

result:

```
1
0
1


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 18, in <module>
    for x in mylist:
  File line 12, in squares
    fin = (avg - val[i]) ** 2
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: You keep incrementing `i` and you never stop the loop.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code there are some variables & methods that you did that I think you can also change. Like example on this one. I commented out your old code so you can see the changes & difference.

```
import statistics as st


def squares(*args):
    #i = 0
    #val = []
    fin = []
    val = args

    for n in val:
        avg = (st.mean(val))
        fin = (avg - n) ** 2  # line 12, #val[i]
        #i += 1
        yield fin


mylist = squares(3, 4, 5)
for x in mylist:  # line 18
    print(x)
```

I can see here that you are trying to access every value of `val` with `fin = (avg - val[i]) **`  But you can also use a `for loop` with it & don't need for a `i` variable as index.  Also what @schwobaseggl is correct, you get the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` because you kept `incrementing` or `adding` up your `i` to the point where you are trying to access a value from your `val` variable that is beyond its length.

Comment: You should be calculating `avg` only once outside the loop..

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the generator function:

```
import statistics as st

def squares(*args):
    avg = st.mean(args)
    for arg in args:
        yield (avg - arg) ** 2
```

Note that in your original, you have an infinite loop (`while True`) that you never `break` and that keeps incrementing index `i` while the `i`-accessed sequence `val` does not grow. That was always an `IndexError` waiting to happen.